# Array of pointers to functions with variable number of arguments

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have the following task to do on my studies:

I have some different methods of sorting such as bubble sort, quick sort, etc.

I have to create an array of pointers, each of them pointing to one of given methods. Then I can execute all sorting methods with for loop.

However, not all sorting functions take the same amount of arguments. I.e:

`void quickSort( int*, int, int );` takes pointer to data array and 2 ints

`void double bubbleSort( int*, int);` takes just one int

I was searching on the Internet and found that the following solution may work:

```
void (*pointer)( ... ) = (void (\*)( ... ))quickSort;
```

But I also heard that such declaration is dangerous and is not recommended.
So here is my question: Is there any safe way to declare such array? What would it look like?

Comment: If the functions take different number of arguments, how are you going to call them in a loop?

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages.  The appropriate answer to your question strongly depends on which language your actually using.  Please select one and remove the other 'tag'

Comment: @eerorika I was thinking about something like: for( for-arguments ){ funPointer( dataArray, argument1, argument2 ) ;fflush(stdin);} since the number of arguments besides date array only varies between 1 and 2. I know it doesn't look nice but my teacher asked my to do such array and I don't know how else should I do this :/

Comment: @BB but in that expression you pass three arguments to the pointed functions. You cannot call functions that take one or two arguments by passing three.

Comment: @eerorika While assigning an adress to a pointer I convert it's type to void (*)( ... ) so I can put in unspecified number of arguments

Comment: @BB Converting the type is irrelevant if you always pass three arguments.

Comment: You need to give the two functions a common interface so they can be called the same way.  If the interface differs from the functions you have now, then the interface can call the existing function with whatever extra parameters it needs.